# Openshift 3 App Deployment Failed: Took longer than 600 seconds to become ready

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift, openshift-3

I have a problem with my openshift 3 setup, based on Node.js + MongoDB (Persistent) https://github.com/openshift/nodejs-ex.git

**Latest App Deployment: nodejs-mongo-persistent-7: Failed**

```
--> Scaling nodejs-mongo-persistent-7 to 1
--> Waiting up to 10m0s for pods in rc nodejs-mongo-persistent-7 to become ready
error: update acceptor rejected nodejs-mongo-persistent-7: pods for rc "nodejs-mongo-persistent-7" took longer than 600 seconds to become ready
```

**Latest Build: Complete**

```
Pushing image 172.30.254.23:5000/husk/nodejs-mongo-persistent:latest ...
Pushed 5/6 layers, 84% complete
Pushed 6/6 layers, 100% complete
Push successful
```

I have no idea how to debug this? Can you help please.

Comment: What OpenShift environment are you using? Some of the Online Starter environments are currently experiencing issues. You can see whether there are current issues as it tells you top right in the web console. https://status.starter.openshift.com/

Comment: My Environment ist Starter: US West (Oregon) – For individual learning and experimenting.

Comment: Then you are likely being affected by the current issues. Keep monitoring the status page. I have no further details than what is shown there.

Comment: Thanks. I've recreated the project but still problem still occurs. Will wait for updates from Openshift

Answer (score 2):

Check what went wrong in console: `oc get events`

`Failed to pull image`? Make sure you included a proper `secret`